# Automatically upgrade RDS instance type under heavy load?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using EC2 quite successfully for an application which have quite sudden bursts of activity once a month, enabling the T2/T3 Unlimited mode on the instance improved reliability while allowing to keep the cost down because most of the time our service is receive really low volumes of traffic.

Despite caching and optimizing our queries our PostgreSQL RDS instance has become a bottleneck due to these increased bursts in traffic, I couldn't find any option similar to the  T2/T3 Unlimited mode for RDS instances.

Is there a way to automatically upgrade RDS instance type when it comes under heavy load?

Comment: Do you have the background to host the PostgreSQL server on an EC2 instance, similar to your other server?  You do take on more maintenance but you get to make these choices.

Comment: @stdunbar it would not be a huge management burden, but i think it would be a hard sell for my client :/

Comment: "automatically upgrade instance type" is different from T2 unlimited. T2 unlimited specifies that you want to pay more instead of being throttled for running out of CPU credits. Is your RDS instance a T2/T3 and is it running out of CPU credits? Upgrading/changing an instance type requires shutting down the instance, moving it to different hardware, and starting it back up. This is true for both EC2 and RDS. I don't think that's what you want to happen in the middle of a burst,since it involves downtime. You should look into RDS Aurora read replicas, or Aurora serverless.

Comment: RDS/Postgres supports t3 instances, and unlimited mode is enabled by default.  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/amazon-rds-postgresql-now-supports-t3-instance-types/